# Need Modal to only show when user clicks Login

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on a mvc6 web application and I'm just having the worst time getting this modal to work correctly. It either shows up every time a user navigates to another screen or it never shows up! The idea is the user can be on any page within access and only when the user clicks login a bootstrap modal should appear. I have the modal in a partial or shared view because it needs to be on all pages but I don't want it to render I just want it to be there if it makes sense but I cant get it to stop popping up and when I do I cant get it to pop up! Maybe I shouldn't be programming ive spent 5 hours on this!

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 0):

I would say just delete this question as it's dumb but anyways the answer.

Create a partial view with the content and logic you desire like so

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="loginModal" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
```

then in your layout or shared view after rendering body content insert the html like so

```
@RenderBody()
            @Html.Partial("_LoginModal")
            <hr />

            <footer class="container body-content">
```

and then in your navbar you need to add this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: well actually it doesn't actually post anything back!